# A category's quotient category of isomorphism types

Tags: category-theory

In an answer to another [question on skeletal categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30032/equivalence-versus-isomorphism-of-categories), it is said:

> "[...] given a category $\mathcal C$, one can *not* define *in general*
>   the structure of a category on the class of isomorphic classes of
>   objects of $\mathcal C$ (to see why, try to define the arrows)."

On the other hand, in a paper entitled "[A category's quotient category of isomorphism types versus its skeleton](http://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4522/1/4522.pdf)", the author seemingly constructs the quotient category of isomorphism types of an *arbitrary* category $\mathcal C$.

> **Question 1:** How does this fit together? Is one of the authors wrong,
>   or do they talk about different things?

A specific example where the quotient category of isomorphism types of objects of a category seems to be definable and is even isomorphic to its skeleton is [FinSet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FinSet) with an arrow from $[A]$ to $[B]$ in the quotient category when there is an monomorphism from $A$ to $B$, i.e. when $A$ is smaller than $B$.

> **Question 2:** Is this one of the exceptions the first author might have in mind when he says "not in general"? Can these exceptions be
>   characterized?

Comment: The first author has some implicit assumptions about what properties the category on the isomorphism classes should have; one could define a category whose objects are the isomorphism classes of objects of $\mathcal{C}$, by giving each object its identity morphism and then stopping. The result would not have a particularly interesting or useful relationship to $\mathcal{C}$ though. So one possibility is that whatever conditions the first author thinks the resulting category should meet are not met by the category defined by the second author.

Comment: It is far from obvious whether or not the category $[\mathcal{C}]$ constructed in the cited paper is skeletal, and it is explicitly stated at the beginning of the paper that $[\mathcal{C}]$ is not even equivalent to $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: @Matt: You are most certainly right. The implicit assumption the first author must have had in mind is: "a category on the class of isomorphism classes of objects of $\mathcal C$ that is isomorphic to the skeleton of $\mathcal C$". This,  I have to admit, makes my question 1 trivial. My question 2 remains "valid", I hope.

Answer (score 4):

**(1): They’re talking about very different things.**

The [question you link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30032/equivalence-versus-isomorphism-of-categories) originally asks whether we can use a quotient construction to *replace* any category by a skeletal category.  Since it’s being proposed to justify always working with skeletal categories, presumably the quotient category is intended to be equivalent to the original one; and this (as per [Angelo’s answer there](https://mathoverflow.net/a/30034/2273)) is not possible without the axiom of choice.  (That is: one can show that if every category has an equivalent skeletal quotient, then AC holds.)

On the other hand, there are several ways that you *could* define a category structure on the class of iso classes of objects of a category — they just won’t usually be skeletal or equivalent to the original category. Trivially, you could use the discrete or codiscrete category structure.

Less trivially, the [Fritsch 1985 paper you link](http://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4522/1/4522.pdf) considers the pushout, over the discrete category on $\mathrm{ob}(\mathbf{C})$, of $\mathbf{C}$ and the discrete category of iso classes of objects of $\mathbf{C}$.  This is perhaps more clearly described by its universal property: functors *out* of it correspond to functors out of $\mathbf{C}$ sending isomorphic objects to equal objects.  Taking $\mathcal{I}$ to be the “walking isomorphism”, the codiscrete category on two objects, one finds that its Fritsch quotient is the group $\mathbb{Z}$ viewed as a one-object category.  (To see this, consider the universal properties.)  This is neither skeletal, nor equivalent to $\mathcal{I}$ itself.

The Fritsch quotient is, while intriguing, a bit unnatural for many purposes: it doesn’t for instance respect equivalence of categories. The example above again shows this: $\mathcal{I}$ is equivalent to the terminal category $1$, whose Fritsch quotient is just itself, which is certainly not equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}$!

**(2): Can the exceptions be classified?**

(“The exceptions” here meaning, presumably, “categories where you *can* put a structure on the class of iso classes, such that the quotient map on objects $q : \mathrm{ob} \mathbf{C} \to \pi_0(\mathbf{C})$ becomes the object map of an equivalence of categories”.)

I don’t know any way to classify these in general, and the equivalence with AC vaguely suggests to me that one shouldn’t expect to (but that’s a very vague gut feeling; I’m not sure how meaningful it is).  However, one very important class of examples is categories of *rigid* objects — categories where if two objects are isomorphic, they are uniquely so; or equivalently, where objects have no non-trivial automorphisms.  I won’t give the details of how to do it for rigid categories; it’s a good exercise.  But ideas related to this example arise naturally in many places — for instance, the construction of *moduli spaces*.  If some kind of object — *widgets,* say — is always rigid, then one can usually construct a nice “space of widgets”.  However, if they have non-trivial automorphisms/symmetries, the “space of widgets” will need to remember this, and so have to be some more complicated object — a *stack* of some sort.  There are some very nice references on this which are eluding me right now; I’m trying to remember/track them down, and will give them when/if I do.